# Search JSON response with python

Tags: python, json

I have searched and searched but I'm not able to figure this out. Below is the JSON data I get back from the web service, API:

```
{
  "total_count": 673, 
  "items": [
    {
      "hap": "delivered", 
      "message": "Delivered: no-reply@example.com \u2192 jon.doe@gmail.com 'Some Email subject'", 
      "type": "info", 
      "created_at": "Wed, 19 Aug 2015 18:38:54 GMT", 
      "message_id": "20150819183853.13720.31771@example.com"
    }, 
    {
      "hap": "accepted", 
      "message": "Accepted: no-reply@example.com \u2192 jon.doe@gmail.com 'Subject of this email here'", 
      "type": "info", 
      "created_at": "Wed, 19 Aug 2015 18:38:53 GMT", 
      "message_id": "20150819183853.13720.31771@example.com"
    }, 
    {
      "hap": "delivered", 
      "message": "Delivered: no-reply@example.com \u2192 jane.doe@gmail.com 'Subject Line here'", 
      "type": "info", 
      "created_at": "Wed, 19 Aug 2015 18:37:50 GMT", 
      "message_id": "20150819183749.13738.20180@example.com"
    },
```

The challenge is that I am trying to search the "message": block for the TO email address which comes after the "\u2192" inside the "message": location.

I have created this python script that dumps all entries inside "message": but I have not been able to filter this with a specific email address.

```
import requests, json
print("Connecting to the URL...")
r = requests.get("https://api:key-12345@api.mailgun.net/v3/example.com/log")
j = r.json()
for data in j['items']:
    print data['message']
```

Comment: Will there only be 1 "To" email address in the message or can there be multiple "To" email addresses in a message?

Comment: And you want to be able to look for a specific email address such as "jane.doe@gmail.com" and then only do something with the message from that specific email?

Comment: There will only be one TO email there. I need to show everything inside "message": that matches the email address searched for. There could be 1 or 50 results with that TO email address.

Comment: Ok, Do you know the email address you will be searching for to start off with or will you need to read some of the messages to find the address first? hope question that makes sense :)

Comment: I'll know what the email address I'll be searching for. This is the mailgun api that pulls logs to show if an email has been delivered for a given address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these "should" work.

Since you already know the email address, you only need to search the string for the exact email addresss. There are a couple of options here. You can use regular expressions (maybe overkill since this isnt a pattern but a known string). You can also just search the string for the known email address.

You determine if you should use the message based of its boolean value in both cases.

## Option 1

Regular Expressions

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#match-objects

```
import re

email_address = "email_address_you_know@somewhere.com"

for data in j['items']:
    match = re.search(email_address, data['message'])
    if match:
        print data['message']
```

## Option 2

Search the message for the email address string

```
email_address = "email_address_you_know@somewhere.com"

for data in j['items']:
    if email_address in data['message']:
        print data['message']
```

Comment: Thanks Dan! I used Option 2! I'm a network engineer by trade trying to get some daily log viewing off my plate and into a web page.

Comment: Oh great, glad that helped. Option 2 was for sure the more appropriate approach for your case now that I realize the details of the task you were doing. Thanks for coming over from the network side to contribute :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
re.findall("[^@ ]+@[^@]+\.[^@ ]+", data['message'].split("\u2192")[1])[0]
```

First I split `data['message']` on two by the character `\u2192` than take the second part. I try to find all emails in this second part, and choose only the first one because it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json.loads` to solve that.

```
>>> json.loads('"Delivered: no-reply@example.com \u2192 jane.doe@gmail.com"')
'Delivered: no-reply@example.com → jane.doe@gmail.com'
```